# Стоит  ли переходить с html 4.01 на html 5

Tags: html, html5

Добрый вечер, Ваше личное мнение стоит переходить на html 5 или нет? Как я понял, чтобы перейти с html 4.01 на html 5, в основном переносить атрибуты тег в атрибут style. Еще стали короче мета-теги и доктайп. И вот я так и не могу еще понять в html5 написано было что не обязательно закрывать одиночные теги (`<img>, <br/>...`), хотя валидатор ругается. Он стоит на режиме html5.

Comment: >Не стоит задавать вопросы-опросы, где каждый ответ является верным, форум - не подходящее место для статистических исследований и реальной ценности подобные темы не имеют.

- [Какие вопросы не стоит задавать?](http://hashcode.ru/faq/)

Comment: Хотелось узнать мнение, вообще я чуть не правильно сформулировал. Хотелось услышать Плюсы и минусы.

Comment: переносить атрибуты тег в атрибут style


Что?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Однозначно переходить!

Answer (score 2):

**ДА!** Но это тот же HTML, только с новыми тегами и атрибутами

Answer (score 0):

> Ваше личное мнение стоит переходить на html 5

## Да!

Answer (score 0):

Лишние знание не будут, причем если этим занимается - это скоро будет стандартом...

Answer (score 0):

Переходить придется

Comment: Придется? Почему? По-моему, обратная совместимость еще будет и будет.

Comment: Ну если вам не нравиться html5, вы, конечно, можете использовать 4ый.
Если вам не нравиться ферари, но вы без ума от волги - никто вам не запретит ездить на волге :)